# android ant build: debug and release targets

Tags: android, ant

According to the 'help' target documentation:

1. *debug*: builds the applications and
   signs it with a debug key
2. *release*; builds the application: the
   generated APK file must be signed
   before it is published

Here is what I found, which is a bit different than what I expected:

**debug**: ignores keystore definitions in `build.properties` whether you specify them or not. Which kesystore file is it using? The same as Eclipse: the default `debug.keystore` file in your Documents and Settings?

It creates two files:

1. -debug-unaligned.apk (signed, unaligned)
2. -debug.apk (signed, aligned)

**release:** 'help' says it doesn't sign it. It creates these files:

1. -unsigned.apk (unsigned, unaligned)

The next two are only if you have the values specified in `build.properties`:

1. -unaligned.apk (signed, unaligned)
2. -release.apk (signed, aligned)

Any helpful comments / verifications will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Which kesystore file is it using? The same as Eclipse: the default debug.keystore file in your Documents and Settings?

Yes.

Comment: Thank you!  I am assuming it's ok for my teammates to overwrite their default debug.keystore files with mine?  Eclipse doesn't try to overwrite this file, right?

Comment: @CommonsWare - Sounds good.  We tried it out and it seems to be working.  My teammate can build from the command line using Ant and can also build from Eclipse.  This post helped us out a lot, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible to make ant get the debug keystore from somewhere else as for release? I know this can be done from Eclipse so I figure it should be possible to do it from a command line too.

Comment: @Scorpio "is it possible to make ant get the debug keystore from somewhere else as for release?" -- perhaps. "so I figure it should be possible to do it from a command line too" -- it definitely is possible using Gradle. Google has been advising developers to stop investing in custom Ant scripts for a bit over a year now.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I know, but old habits die hard and the project I am working on still supports ant...

Answer (score 7):

As far as the release target goes, you will get behaviour like this:

If you have lines like:

```
key.store=c:/users/me/my-release-key.keystore
key.alias=release_alias
key.store.password=myStorePassword
key.alias.password=myAliasPassword
```

in your build.properties, it will automatically build and sign your apk with no prompting for anything.

If you comment out the last two lines, then it will prompt you for the passwords, then complete a signed build if the passwords are OK.

If you don't have any of the above lines, then it will just build you an unsigned apk with no prompting for anything and end with:

```
-release-nosign:
[echo] No key.store and key.alias properties found in build.properties.
[echo] Please sign C:\dev\projects\AntBuilds\MyProject\bin\MyProject-unsigned.apk manually
[echo] and run zipalign from the Android SDK tools.
```

.

Comment: That's what I thought: the 'release' part of help could use a little clarification probably, but you find it out the 1st time you do it. I like the prompting for passwords processing.

Answer (score 1):

This answer works for me, I am using ant to auto-compile android app, it prompts and need password, I wrote one file named password, and using the command ---ant release < passwd,
However, it also prompts that I need input password.

Using the tips here

```
key.store=c:/users/me/my-release-key.keystore
key.alias=release_alias
key.store.password=myStorePassword
key.alias.password=myAliasPassword
```

I solved this problem.